csrss.exe , using 10% gpu
This is my pc (relevant) setup:
System: windows 10
Intel: i5-9600k
GPU: nvidia 2060 super
My system is on samsung 960v ssd
The problem: each time I’m moving my mouse the csrss.exe is jumping to 14% (sometimes 21%) but then stay on 10% (and sometimes on 5.7 - 4.7%) and I have updated my gpu driver and the problem still there.
Anyone know how to fix it?
Thanks for anyone who will answer
